# Rails autocomplete with javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm using Awesomplete to help with autocompletion of a list of towns in a rails 6 application. Everything is working as it should, but once a town is selected it shows the value in the put field instead of the name of the town. Is it possible to show the name once a town is selected but still search by the value?

**Form**

```
<%= text_field_tag(:location, value = nil, html_options = {class: 'form-control', id: 'myLocation', placeholder: 'Start typing a town name'}) %>
<%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
```

**Javascript**

```
var input = document.getElementById("myLocation");
    new Awesomplete(input, {
        list: [['Town 1',100],['Town 2',200]...]
    });
```

Once search is implemented it takes the '100' or '200' value from the array and passes it into the location params.

**Controller**

```
data = HTTParty.get("https://www.urlofapi.com/params[:location]}")
@ddcalc = JSON.parse(data.body)
```

Comment: Ideally it should show the name of the location in the autocomplete input and pass it's value to the server as per above snippet. What issue you are facing?

Comment: It’s showing the town name in the autocomplete. Once a town is selected it show the number value in the input. Ie. 100 instead of Town 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly replace the 'this.input.value' as below

```
new Awesomplete(input, {
  list: [
    { label: "Town 1", value: "100" },
    { label: "Town 2", value: "200" }
  ],
  replace: function(suggestion) {
    this.input.value = suggestion.label; // You can assign label or value as per your need
  }
});
```

If you want to search with 100, 200 and want to display Town 1 in textbox then

```
new Awesomplete(input, {
  list: [
   { label: "100", value: "Town 1" },
   { label: "200", value: "Town 2" }
  ],
  replace: function(suggestion) {
    this.input.value = suggestion.value; // You can assign label or value as per your need
  }
 });
```

if this params[:location] is needed id i am suggesting you to use a hidden field to  keep suggestion.label

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has an example for this under the "[Basic Usage](https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/#basic-usage)" section:

> ```
> // Show label and insert label into the input:
> new Awesomplete(input, {
>     list: [
>         { label: "Belarus", value: "BY" },
>         { label: "China", value: "CN" },
>         { label: "United States", value: "US" }
>     ],
>     // insert label instead of value into the input.
>     replace: function(suggestion) {
>         this.input.value = suggestion.label;
>     }
> });
> ```

Applying this for your given example would result in:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("myLocation");
new Awesomplete(input, {
    list: [['Town 1', 100], ['Town 2', 200]],
    replace: function (suggestion) {
        this.input.value = suggestion.label;
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesomplete/1.1.5/awesomplete.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesomplete/1.1.5/awesomplete.min.js"></script>

<input id="myLocation"    type="text" />
```

This might result in the label being submitted rather than the value. However you could opt for a solution where you set a separate (hidden) input that is updated with the value belonging to the label.

```js
const locations = { "Town 1": 100, "Town 2": 200 },
      locationLabel = document.getElementById("locationLabel"),
      locationValue = document.getElementById("locationValue"),
      setLocationValue = function (event) {
        const label = event.target.value;
        locationValue.value = locations.hasOwnProperty(label)
                            ? locations[label]
                            : "";
      };

new Awesomplete(locationLabel, { list: Object.keys(locations) });
locationLabel.addEventListener("input", setLocationValue);
locationLabel.addEventListener("awesomplete-selectcomplete", setLocationValue);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesomplete/1.1.5/awesomplete.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesomplete/1.1.5/awesomplete.min.js"></script>

<input id="locationLabel" type="text" />
<input id="locationValue" type="text" placeholder="hide this input" />
```